# How can I prevent the page from reloading after posting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Normally, I'd use AJAX for this, but the purpose of the form is to upload a file, which AJAX can't do.

Is there a way to let the form submit normally, but catch the response (JSON/XML or similar) and handle it in javascript without the page refreshing/redirecting?

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: In modern browsers you can use Ajax for uploading files.

Comment: @undefined It's expected that older browsers will use this page.

Comment: Ajax itself doesn't upload a file but javascript should be able to send bytes (which is what a file is) to a URL and accomplish something similar.

Comment: @Dom Sure, if you really think it will help. It's just a simple form with a single file input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a hidden iframe, post the form to the iframe using the target attribute.